What does "execution contains an undefined operation" actually mean?
C++ (n4917.pdf), 4.1.2p5 (emphasis added):

A conforming implementation executing a well-formed program shall produce the same observable behavior as
one of the possible executions of the corresponding instance of the abstract machine with the same program
and the same input. However, if any such execution contains an undefined operation, this document places
no requirement on the implementation executing that program with that input (not even with regard to
operations preceding the first undefined operation).

What does "execution contains an undefined operation" actually mean?
Is it about a presence (i.e. w/o an execution) of an undefined operation, or is it about an execution of an undefined operation?

Are you asking if "execution" is about "execution"?

@ScottHunter No. I'm asking if "execution contains an undefined operation" is about a presence (i.e. w/o an execution) of an undefined operation, or about an execution of an undefined operation.

If "undefined operation" is the same as "undefined behavior", it's well known that you don't have to execute the ill-formed code to get unexpected behavior.  See Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest) for some fun examples.

@MarkRansom Thanks for the link (I'm aware if it). Does it mean that "execution contains an undefined operation" is about a presence (i.e. w/o an execution) of an undefined operation?

I don't see how "if any such execution contains an undefined operation" could be interpreted as "if the lack of execution contains an undefined operation". There are many possible executions of the abstract machine in response to an input, because some things are left to the discretion of the implementation. If any abstract machine execution contains an undefined operation, then the program's results are undefined.

If your path of execution has UB then your entire program has UB.  If the UB is never executed then you don't.

@RaymondChen I'll rephase from the "compiler point of view": if compiler proved that a program contains an undefined operation, which will be executed, then may the compiler invalidate the whole program (e.g. skip / cancel / change operations preceding the first undefined operation)? In other words: what is the "invalidation trigger": a presence (w/o an execution) of an undefined operation OR an actual execution of an undefined operation?

The presence without execution of an invalid operation is fine. You do this all the time! if (p) return *p; There the presence of an invalid operation here (dereferencing a null pointer) but you also made sure that it never executes (by putting it inside an if). However, if the compiler can prove that any particular *p happens when p is null, then that error can affect operations that preceded the dereference. (Note that your "in other words" is different from the "compiler point of view" part of the sentence.)

@NathanOliver Consider a program P that does A, B, . A compiler sees / proves that P contains an undefined operation, which will be executed. As I understand, in that case per C++ A and/or B may be invalidated (i.e. skipped / canceled / changed). My question is: who is allowed to do the invalidation: a compiler (i.e. at compile time; the undefined operation is not executed) OR a program itself (i.e. at run time; the undefined operation is executed)? Or both?

You are confusing execution by the abstract machine with execution by the physical machine. If the abstract machine executes the undefined operation, then the physical machine is permitted to do whatever it wants. "Whatever it wants" includes "crashing", or "not doing it at all". This discrepancy between the abstract and physical machines happens all the time, thanks to the "as-if" rule. The abstract machine calculates 1+2, but the physical machine skips the addition opcode and just uses 3.

@pmor The compiler is the one that does the "invalidation" since C++ is a compiled language.

It'll be things like hey, this loop has to end so even though it never ends because of a bug the compiler is free to assume it does and write machine code with that assumption.

@RaymondChen Thanks. So, "execution contains an undefined operation" means that such "undefined operation" need not (i.e. not required) be actually executed (on a physical machine). Is that correct?

No.  The UB must be executed for it to "exist".

@NathanOliver This is what I'm trying to figure out: whether "execution contains an undefined operation" is an actual execution (on say a physical machine) of an undefined operation OR, for example, a prove / knowledge that an undefined operation will be executed (on say a physical machine).

C++ doesn't care about the physical machine.  Everything we are talking about is the Abstract Machine that the C++ standard uses do define what is legal and what is not.  If according to the rules of the abstract machine if your path of execution goes through an expression which has undefined behavior then the entire execution has undefined behavior.  If the path of execution never executes an undefined operation then you are okay, even if there is UB present in a path that you never execute.

@NathanOliver Thanks. I infeed confused the abstract machine with the concrete (e.g. physical) machine. Re: "the entire execution has undefined behavior": to remind: this is not true for C: there all observable behavior preceding an undefined operation shall appear. I didn't know about this difference between C and C++ w.r.t. UB.

The difference is C++ makes the entire program UB if any part of the execution has UB.  That means that UB in C++ can "time travel" and earlier or later code way not work as expected.

@NathanOliver What "making the entire program UB" was made for the sake of? Performance increase? Less compiler complexity?

I would say that most likely compiler complexity is the reason.

@NathanOliver Indeed, "provides no guarantee" usually means / implies "less complex implementation" (e.g. less if-conditions).

It can very definitely result from performance optimizations.  For example, the compiler can reorder memory access of non-volatile objects.  If it chooses to prefetch an object so that the memory controller can be working in parallel with the processor, and that prefetch is through a null pointer, then you can observe the side effects (whatever those may be, UB gives no guarantees, but in practice you could get SIGSEGV) in the middle of other operations.

Allowing the compiler to propagate UB backwards in time makes it easier for compilers, because they don't have to generate code to actively trap UB and prevent it from affect the result of earlier calculations. They can just let the UB corrupt memory and (say) corrupt the buffers of files whose contents haven't been flushed, causing the observed effect to be that a previous "write" operation failed to write the correct data.

It simply says if any of the code you write is not well-formed, and not left to the implementation (compiler) to define, then when the program counter reaches  the instructions produced by that code -- ANYTHING can happen. In other words, what your program does at that point is no longer defined and is no way guaranteed to be reproducible. It simply states that undefined behavior (UB) will occur.

@NathanOliver Re: "The UB must be executed for it to "exist": indeed, a consequence / effect cannot happen w/o a cause.

The abstract machine is parametrized by aspects that are stated to be implementation-defined in the standard, see [intro.abstract]/2.
Each realization of implementation-defined behavior realizes one instance of the abstract machine.
Each such instance of the abstract machine can be run for any program with any given input and is non-deterministic. Its non-deterministic aspects are behavior that the standard states to be unspecified. Each realization of all unspecified behaviors then determines one deterministic execution on the instance of the abstract machine for the given program and input, which are the operations performed by the abstract machine according to the program execution rules specified in the rest of the standard given the realizations of implementation-defined and unspecified behavior for that program and input. See [intro.abstract]/3.
Your quote states that, given the C++ program and any particular realization of program inputs, if any execution (i.e. realization of unspecified behaviors) would result in executing an operation that has undefined behavior, then the compiler does not have to guarantee any particular behavior of the program for that input.
Otherwise the compiler has to assure that the observable behavior of the program with the given input corresponds to the observable behaviors that at least one execution (i.e. realization of unspecified behaviors) would have on the instance of the abstract machine.
All of this is talking about executions on the abstract machine, not actual execution of the compiled code. The point of view is external, also to the time dimension. When determining whether the compiler needs to guarantee any particular behavior, we look at all inputs to the program for the whole execution. If the program would have undefined behavior in one realization of unspecified behavior for a given such set of inputs over the whole execution time, then there are no requirements on observable behavior at all, not even at the start of the program execution, if these inputs will occur.
Of course, in practice user inputs are not deterministic and we can't predict future inputs, so as long as inputs that would not cause undefined behavior are possible, we have to make sure that the program can produce valid observable behavior for such inputs.
But if we can determine at some point that the program execution will for any possible future set of inputs have undefined behavior for one realization of unspecified behaviors per such input realization, then there is no requirement to produce any particular observable behavior anymore, even if naively following the ongoing execution according to the rules of the abstract machine would produce further observable behavior before the undefined operation or the user input leading to the undefined operation occurs.

Re: "no requirements on observable behavior": in C there is (OB  preceding an undefined operation shall appear). I wonder whether C++ places (in this case) no requirements on OB for the sake of performance increase. Any knowledge / ideas / comments on that?

The concept of "observable behavior" was introduced in C11, which is long after C++ split off into a separate language. C++ retains the pre-C11 rules for undefined behavior. If you feel that C++ should be updated to align with C on this matter, you are welcome to submit a proposal to the C++ committee.

@pmor I think the comment above was directed at you but missed the notification. I do not know about the history and rational. Because these rules have been in similar form already in C++98 it is also difficult to find committee documentation about it.

There is a great answer already. I just want to give a concrete example to clarify things.
Given this program:
#include <iostream>

int ub()
{
    int* bad = nullptr;
    return *bad;
}

int main()
{
    int input;

    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;

    std::cin >> input;
    std::cout << "Point A" << std::endl;

    if (input == 42)
    {
        std::cout << "Point B" << std::endl;
        ub();
        std::cout << "Point C" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Point D" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Bye!" << std::endl;
}

 From now on I talk about running the program, executing the program on a physical machine with a specified input.
For any integer input except 42 the program is required to exhibit this exact behavior:

Print to stdout:
Hello
Point A
Point D
Bye


Terminate (also return 0 to the caller)

For the integer input 42 the program exhibits Undefined Behavior. Thus it has no defined behavior. It is not required to output anything specific if any, it is not required to terminate, it can crash etc.
To make it more clear: it is not required to output either Point A or Point B for which the executing operation would be before the execution of the UB operation.
Furthermore, even though at time of execution of "std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;" it is not yet known if the execution of the program is UB or not, theoretically if the input is 42 the program is not required to output Hello.
Of course in practice the program will output Hello. However if the line were missing << std::endl, so the line would not be flushed, for the run of the program with input 42 in practice it is possible that Hello won't be printed.

I've been around a long... time, but what is ?

It's the "Circled Information Source" unicode symbol. I have a AutoHotkey script to quickly type various unicode symbols I find useful like → ⇒ » • ✅ ▲ ⚠ π Δ λ ∞ and so on

Thank you. Learned something new today, and that's a good day. Old dog got his new trick!

Re: "For any integer input except 42...": How Point B Point C can be printed for integer input, say, 43?

Oh God, that is such a big blunder. Corrected. Thank you!

As user Raymond Chen commented, I'm indeed confusing execution by the abstract machine with execution by the concrete (e.g. physical) machine.
When asking (and commenting) I thought about the concrete (e.g. physical) machine.
As I understand, if compiler proved that a program contains an (executable, i.e. not "dead code") undefined operation, then execution of such undefined operation already happened (at translation time, at "abstract machine level"), which is the trigger for the potential (whole program) invalidation (e.g. skipping / cancelling / changing operations preceding the first undefined operation).

It has nothing to do with whether or not there is non-dead code with undefined behavior. The "trigger" is per set of user inputs. You can't say that the whole program is invalidated, only that it is invalidated for the given set of inputs. Specifically it is decided by whether, for the given realized user inputs, any possible execution of the abstract machine contains an undefined operation. Just having some code with undefined behavior in the program doesn't matter if the realized user input doesn't cause it to be executed (on the abstract machine).
